# how to update with several conditions

Tags: mysql

In MySQL how can I Update last occurrence of rows which have a column with either 1, 4 or 5.

This is what I want to achieve: That 10% of a certain amount (from user input) be added to the AVAILABLE AMOUNT in the record of the managers whose MEMBERSHIP TYPE column is manager where they are have not make withdraw on that column.

This is my code

```
$superManager ="UPDATE transactions SET GETAMOUNT=GETAMOUNT+$tenpercent 
WHERE loginID='1' && loginID='4' && loginID='5'
WHERE TRANSACTION STATUS='not-yet-withdrawn'";
```

Answer (score 0):

change your where condition 
you can not use two time Where key word

```
$superManager ="UPDATE transactions SET GETAMOUNT=GETAMOUNT+$tenpercent 
WHERE (loginID='1' OR loginID='4' OR loginID='5')
and STATUS='not-yet-withdrawn'";
```